# Centre error bars on geom_bar and centre bars on label axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a different number of "fill" options in my dataset and error bars for only one of these options. I've come up with 2 variations and either the bars are not centered over the x-axis label or the error bar is not displayed over the correct bar. Is there any way to create a bar plot where each bar is the same width, centered on the x-axis label and the error bar associated with the type is centered over the bar?

Ideally there is also a small space between the bars like in fig_2 example below.

Some sample data:

```
sample.data <- data.frame(Type = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b"),
                   Value = c(63, 123, 73, 79, 94),
                   Name = c("Item A","Item A","Item A", "Item B", "Item B"),
                   SD = c(3, NA, NA, 5, NA))
```

A plot where the error bars are centered above the correct bar and all bars are the same width, but the bars are not centered over the X axis label.

```
fig_1 <- sample.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Value, x = Name, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(preserve="single"),
           width = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge(0.8, preserve = "single"),
                aes(ymin=Value-SD, ymax=Value+SD), width=.2)
```

[fig_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqmu9.png)

A plot where the bars are centered over the axis label and are all the same width, but error bars are not centered over the correct bar.

```
fig_2 <- sample.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Value, x = Name, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"),
           width = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(stat="Identity",
                position=position_dodge2(0.8, preserve = "single"),
                aes(ymin=Value-SD, ymax=Value+SD), width=.2)

fig_2
```

[fig_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkg3.png)

Edit:

This is what I want my figure to look like:
[image: This is what I want my figure to look like]

Edit 2:

Randomized data similar to my own:

```
sample.data.2 <- data.frame('Fruit' = c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Pear'),
'Source' =  c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
'SD' =  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08, 0.09, 0.07, 0.02, 0.09 ),
'Cost' =  c(12.05, 10.5, 10.46, 9.14, 11.34, 10, 11.43, 12.86, 12.69, 9.42, 9.74, 10.01, 11.98, 9.31, 12.2))
```

Edit 3:

dput of sample.data

```
structure(list(Type = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", 
"a", "c"), Value = c(63, 123, 73, 79, 94, 84, 48, 68, 75, 68), 
    Name = c("Item A", "Item A", "Item A", "Item B", "Item B", 
    "Item D", "Item D", "Item D", "Item C", "Item C"), SD = c(3, 
    NA, NA, 5, NA, 7, NA, NA, 4, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

dput of sample.data.2

```
structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Orange", 
    "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", 
    "Banana", "Mango", "Orange", "Pear"), Source = c("A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"), 
        SD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.08, 0.09, 
        0.07, 0.02, 0.09), Cost = c(12.05, 10.5, 10.46, 9.14, 11.34, 
        10, 11.43, 12.86, 12.69, 9.42, 9.74, 10.01, 11.98, 9.31, 
        12.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: SD for Ab, Ac and Bb are NA, so no errorbars are shown. The errorbars are placed on the correct geom_bars (Aa and Ba, which both have a value for SD). What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I am looking to make the error bars in the fig_2 example centered over the geom_bars Aa and Ba. I want the geom_bars centered over the x-axis label. Thanks!